# How to generate a dataframe of proportions in R based on a number of dummy variables?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe in R that has an ID number, and about 5 categorical variables indicating if each ID falls into a certain category. For example:

```
ID #  category1 category2 category3 category4 category5
1      1          0        1         0          0
2      0          0        0         0          0
3      1          1        1         0          0
```

I want to create a dateframe that shows the proportion of 1's in each category. So for example, my desired dataframe would look like this:

```
          category1 category2 category3 category4 category5
proportion  22.23%   16.78%    34.56%      9.31%     3.45%
```

I would also then like to take this dataframe and create bargraphs with each category on the x-axis and the proportion of 1's on the y-axis.

I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this than using dplyr to count 1's for each group then divide by total observations and merge together, which is what I have been doing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: For a binary variable, the proportion is the mean. Using base R, `colMeans(your_data[-1])`, using `dplyr` `select(your_data, -ID) %>% mutate_all(mean)`. You can then you `barplot()` to make a barplot.

Comment: Are these always "1"s? if so, just take the mean of each column (and multiply by 100 for percentage)

Answer (score 0):

```
# create some data
N = 500
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:N, 
                 category1 = sample(c(1,0), N, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.4,0.6)),
                 category2 = sample(c(1,0), N, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.8,0.2)),
                 category3 = sample(c(1,0), N, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5,0.5)),
                 category4 = sample(c(1,0), N, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3,0.7)),
                 category5 = sample(c(1,0), N, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.9,0.1)))

# calculate column percentages
df.percent <- colMeans(df[,-1])

# graph barplot
b <- barplot( df.percent, 
              ylim = c(0,1), 
              col=rgb(0.2,0.4,0.6,0.6))

# Add text
text(b,  df.percent, labels=paste0(round(df.percent, 2),"%"), pos=3)
```

[image]